# Centos 7 - Upgrade ImageMagick

Tags: centos7, imagemagick

I need to upgrade my ImageMagick version in order to fix the following issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754861/imagemagick-convert-different-results-on-two-different-servers

My current version seems to have a bug in some of the features I need.

**CentOS version:**

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611
```

**ImageMagick verison:**

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2016-06-16 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

I have enabled the **Remi repos** in order to install a newer ImageMagick, this is what I get:

```
yum --showduplicates list ImageMagick6

Available Packages
ImageMagick6.x86_64                                                 6.9.9.33-1.el7.remi                                                 remi
ImageMagick6.x86_64                                                 6.9.9.34-1.el7.remi                                                 remi
```

The 6.9 version works for me, but I have the following questions:

- What's the difference between the **ImageMagick** (Default) and the **ImageMagick6** (Remi) package?
- Can I install the ImageMagick6 package in order to upgrade my current ImageMagick installation?
- Is there another option for the upgrade? It's really frustrating that the specific feature I need doesn't work, I would really like to upgrade.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the difference between the ImageMagick (Default) and the ImageMagick6 (Remi) package?

Explained in [ImageMagick6 and ImageMagick7](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/12/12/ImageMagick6-and-ImageMagick7) blog post

> Can I install the ImageMagick6 package in order to upgrade my current ImageMagick installation?

Yes, if nothing requires the old version library.

> Is there another option for the upgrade? It's really frustrating that the specific feature I need doesn't work, I would really like to upgrade.

AFAIK, no (using packages), still possible to build from sources and install in another location.

Comment: Thanks Remi!, the blog post is very useful. I think I'll upgrade with your repo. As a last option I'll build from source and install in another location as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks again Remi, I  installed ImageMagick 6.9.9 with your repos and my issue has gone!